# JQL for Sprint name starting with a character

Tags: jql

I am trying to retrieve the Sprint name that starts with character 'v' of a certain project.
So far i have this jql query:

```
Sprint in closedSprints() AND Sprint = v AND project = [my_project_name] ORDER BY Sprint DESC
```

However, even tho' it looks like "Sprint=v" works, it does not. No filtering is done. Can you help with a different approach?